# How to approximate a half-cosine curve with bezier paths in SVG?

Tags: svg, graphics, trigonometry, bezier, spline

Suppose I want to approximate a half-cosine curve in SVG using bezier paths. The half cosine should look like this:

[image: half cosine]

and runs from [x0,y0] (the left-hand control point) to [x1,y1] (the right-hand one).

How can I find an acceptable set of coefficients for a good approximation of this function?

**Bonus question**: how is it possible to generalize the formula for, for example, a quarter of cosine?

Please note that I **don't** want to approximate the cosine with a series of interconnected segments, I'd like to calculate a good approximation using a Bezier curve.

I tried the solution in comments, but, with those coefficients, the curve seems to end after the second point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw sine waves with SVG (+JS)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932704/how-to-draw-sine-waves-with-svg-js)

Comment: Paul LeBeau is right - have a look at the [answer dealing with Bézier control points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932704/how-to-draw-sine-waves-with-svg-js#13935397)

Comment: I don't honestly know to apply the answer. Let's say I use a cubic bezier with 0,0 1/2,1/2 1,1 π/2,1, I tried something like: `'M' + x0 + "," + y0 + ' C' + x0 * 0.5 + ',' + y0 * 0.5 + ' ' + x1 * 1 + ',' + y1 * 1 + ' ' + x1 * Math.PI / 2 + ',' + y1 * 1;`, but it obvioulsy goes past my right point.

Comment: @ThomasW I see you're one of the answerer there, what am I missing about the control points? A cubic bezier has the origin point, two control points and the end point. What should be the control points be, given start and end?

Comment: All four points (including start and end point) [are called control points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Terminology).

Comment: @ThomasW: ok, so shouldn't the last points be 1,1 instead of π/2,1? I tried to draw a Bezier with those constrol points and obviously it goes over the end point on the right. I'm just trying to understand how to scale those control points to make a bezier approximation that starts with the start piunt and ends at the end point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After few tries/errors, I found that the correct ratio is *K=0.37*.

```
"M" + x1 + "," + y1
+ "C" + (x1 + K * (x2 - x1)) + "," + y1 + ","
+ (x2 - K * (x2 - x1)) + "," + y2 + ","
+ x2 + "," + y2
```

Look at this samples to see how Bezier matches with cosine: http://jsfiddle.net/6165Lxu6/

The green line is the real cosine, the black one is the Bezier. Scroll down to see 5 samples. Points are random at each refresh.

For the generalization, I suggest to use clipping.

Answer (score 24):

Let's assume you want to keep the tangent horizontal on both ends. So naturally the solution is going to be symmetric, and boils down to finding a first control point in horizontal direction.

I wrote a program to do this:

```js
/*
* Find the best cubic Bézier curve approximation of a sine curve.
*
* We want a cubic Bézier curve made out of points (0,0), (0,K), (1-K,1), (1,1) that approximates
* the shifted sine curve (y = a⋅sin(bx + c) + d) which has its minimum at (0,0) and maximum at (1,1).
* This is useful for CSS animation functions.
*
*      ↑      P2         P3
*      1      ×•••••••***×
*      |           ***
*      |         **
*      |        *
*      |      **
*      |   ***
*      ×***•••••••×------1-→
*      P0         P1
*/

const sampleSize = 10000; // number of points to compare when determining the root-mean-square deviation
const iterations = 12; // each iteration gives one more digit

// f(x) = (sin(π⋅(x - 1/2)) + 1) / 2 = (1 - cos(πx)) / 2
const f = x => (1 - Math.cos(Math.PI * x)) / 2;

const sum = function (a, b, c) {
  if (Array.isArray(c)) {
      return [...arguments].reduce(sum);
  }
  return [a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]];
};

const times = (c, [x0, x1]) => [c * x0, c * x1];

// starting points for our iteration
let [left, right] = [0, 1];
for (let digits = 1; digits <= iterations; digits++) {
    // left and right are always integers (digits after 0), this keeps rounding errors low
    // In each iteration, we divide them by a higher power of 10
    let power = Math.pow(10, digits);
    let min = [null, Infinity];
    for (let K = 10 * left; K <= 10 * right; K+= 1) { // note that the candidates for K have one more digit than previous `left` and `right`
        const P1 = [K / power, 0];
        const P2 = [1 - K / power, 1];
        const P3 = [1, 1];

        let bezierPoint = t => sum(
            times(3 * t * (1 - t) * (1 - t), P1),
            times(3 * t * t * (1 - t), P2),
            times(t * t * t, P3)
        );

        // determine the error (root-mean-square)
        let squaredErrorSum = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++) {
            let t = i / sampleSize / 2;
            let P = bezierPoint(t);
            let delta = P[1] - f(P[0]);
            squaredErrorSum += delta * delta;
        }
        let deviation = Math.sqrt(squaredErrorSum); // no need to divide by sampleSize, since it is constant

        if (deviation < min[1]) {
            // this is the best K value with ${digits + 1} digits
            min = [K, deviation];
        }
    }
    left = min[0] - 1;
    right = min[0] + 1;
    console.log(`.${min[0]}`);
}
```

To simplify calculations, I use the normalized sine curve, which passes through `(0,0)` and `(1,1)` as its minimal / maximal points. This is also useful for CSS animations.

It returns **`(.3642124232,0)`**<sup>*</sup> as the point with the smallest root-mean-square deviation (about `0.00013`).

I also created a [Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mtdihhagsx) that shows the accuracy:

[image: Desmos Graph (sine approximation with cubic Bézier curve)]
(Click to try it out - you can drag the control point left and right)

---

<sup>*</sup> Note that there are rounding errors when doing math with JS, so the value is presumably accurate to no more than 5 digits or so.

Answer (score 17):

Because a Bezier curve cannot exactly reconstruct a sinusoidal curve, there are many ways to create an approximation. I am going to assume that our curve starts at the point (0, 0) and ends at (1, 1).

**Simple method**

A simple way to approach this problem is to construct a Bezier curve **B** with the control points (K, 0) and ((1 - K), 1) because of the symmetry involved and the desire to keep a horizontal tangent at t=0 and t=1.

Then we just need to find a value of K such that the derivative of our Bezier curve matches that of the sinusoidal at t=0.5, i.e., [image: pi / 2].

Since the [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_derivative#First_derivative) of our [Bezier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B%C3%A9zier_curves) is given by [image: \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} = \frac{d(3(1-t)t^2+t^3)/dt}{d(3(1-t)^2tK+3(1-t)t^2(1-K)+t^3)/dt}], this simplifies to [image: d] at the point t=0.5.

Setting this equal to our desired derivative, we obtain the solution [image: K=\frac{\pi-2}{\pi}\approx0.36338022763241865692446494650994255\ldots]

Thus, our approximation results in:

```
cubic-bezier(0.3633802276324187, 0, 0.6366197723675813, 1)
```

*and it comes very close with a root mean square deviation of about 0.000224528:*

[image: cubic bezier approximation compared with sinusoidal]

**Advanced Method**

For a better approximation, we may want to minimize the [root mean square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) of their difference instead. This is more complicated to calculate, as we are now trying to find the value of K in the interval (0, 1) that minimizes the following expression:

[image: \int ^{1}_{0} \left( B_y\left(t\right) - \frac{ 1 - \cos \left( \pi B_x \left( t \right) \right) }{2} \right)^2 B_x'\left( t \right) dt]

where B is defined as follows:

[image: B_x(t) = 3\left(1-t\right)^2tK+3\left(1-t\right)t^2\left(1-K\right)+t^3; B_y(t) = 3\left(1-t\right)t^2+t^3]

```
cubic-bezier(0.364212423249, 0, 0.635787576751, 1)
```

Comment: And using Casteljau's method I obtain the quarter-cosine spline as `M 0,0 C 0.18169,0 0.340845,0.25 0.5,0.5` where the two numbers are K/2 and (K+1)/4, respectively

Comment: And the quarter-cosine with the RMS K is `M 0,0 C 0.182106,0 0.341053,0.25 0.5,0.5`

Comment: Having the same derivative in .5 seems to "make sense", but is there any mathematical reason why this would yield a good approximation?

Comment: ThomasR, With three points, we have an approximation and unique solution that is able to match both the points and "slopes" (derivative) at t=0, t=0.5, and t=1. Having two points at t=0, t=1, we wouldn't have a unique solution. At all three points, the lines cross in the same direction and meet at the same points.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading this article on the math of bezier curves and ellipses, as this is basicly what you want (draw a part of an ellipse):
http://www.spaceroots.org/documents/ellipse/elliptical-arc.pdf

it provides some of the insights required.

then look at this graphic:
http://www.svgopen.org/2003/papers/AnimatedMathematics/ellipse.svg

where an example is made for an ellipse

now that you get the math involved, please see this example in LUA ;)
http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Harmonic_partials_on_strings.svg

tada...