# How to create a half-sin-like Easing function in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Is there some way to create a function like `Easing.HalfSin` in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

[Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50596945/9878135) we can create an approximate function using `bezier`:

```js
const EasingHalfSin = Easing.bezier(0.364212423249, 0, 0.635787576751, 1);
```

and then use it like any other easing function:

```js
Animated.timing(position, {
    toValue: 150,
    duration: 1000,
    useNativeDriver: true,
    easing: EasingHalfSin,
}),
```